# What are the two basic experiments to identify different phases in high $T_c$ cuprates systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, phase-transition, superconductivity

what are the two basic experiments to identify different phases like antiferromagnetic, pseudogap, superconducting, strange metal and fermi-liquid  in high $T_c$ cuprates systems like BSCCO and YBCO?

Comment: Are you thinking of [X-ray crystallography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography) and [Nuclear magnetic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance)?

Comment: @mmesser314 But how does they change in their behavior for various phases of high Tc cuprates?